# Find a string which will always be sorted next to a given string, regardless of other elements

Tags: string, sorting

Let's say I have some string `s1` and a sorting function `f`, is it possible to find some other string, `s2`, such that for all other strings `f([s1, s2, ..., sn])` `s2` is always immediately after `s1`.

What is necessary to find this? e.g., are assumptions about the length and/or composition of `s1` and `s2` required, do we need to know the sorting function?

As a concrete example - I have a buch of strings `customer-someCustomerName` and I need to specify to mongodb the `minKey="customer-someCustomerName"` and the `maxKey=...` where maxKey is exactly `"customer-someCustomerName" + 1`. As far as I know, it is just a standard alphabetical sort. I have no control over the customer names (they don't even all start with "customer-" they start with some customer prefix, of which there are currently 7, but will be more)

In the specific case of a standard alphabetical sort (and assuming alphanumeric values), is it enough to just append a "0" to the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your alphabet is *Σ = { a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>, ..., a<sub>n</sub> }* and the sorting function compares the strings lexicographically with *a<sub>1</sub> < a<sub>2</sub> < ... < a<sub>n</sub>* then the successor string to **S** would be **Sa<sub>1</sub>**. For the case of *Σ = [0-9A-Za-z]* that's indeed the same as appending '0' at the end. However there are other characters that precede '0' in ASCII, e.g. '!' or SPACE, or the control ones. Take the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) and go with the smallest value that your sorting function/database engine supports.

Comment: As I wrote the question I suspected this may be the case - thanks for the details though, that does make complete sense.  Fortunately I don't need to consider non alphanumeric characters